# Magento 2 - How to add compare product and My orders link in header dropdown after logging in?

Tags: magento2, theme

[image: header-part]

As I require compare product and my order link in user dropdown shown in image below My account. I tried to edit header.phtml file. which only displays

```
<div class="panel wrapper">
<div class="panel header">
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("header.links"); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Where exactly should I edit??

Your Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\link.phtml**

```
<li class="link module" data-bind="scope: 'module'">
    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl().'catalog/product_compare/index/'; ?>" title="<?php echo __('Compare'); ?>">&nbsp;>> <?php echo __('Compare'); ?></a>
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "wishlist": {
                        "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Replace `<li class="link module" data-bind="scope: 'module'">` with you `Module` Name

Comment: HI Ankit, Have made the changes as per said but no changes displayed. Have added the code in this file :-    magento/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/compare/link.phtml

Comment: Have u created Module for this or only this file u have?

Comment: Not created module for this, actually I was making changes in the existing file present in app/code/magento/modulename.

Comment: U can create new module or  U can add in ur existing custom module